# Chrome is wrongly detecting can it play HLS video media

Tags: javascript, video, http-live-streaming

I am trying to programatically find out whether some media will play or not based on it's URL.

Based on browser testing, HLS will play fine on my Chrome browser using the videoJs player video library, however CanIUse is saying it won't which is my first confusion.

[image]

I am then running it through this JavaScript...

using this npm package to get the mime-types

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types

```
var mime = require('mime-types');

// get the extension of the file
var mimeType = mime.contentType(file.split('.').pop());

// returns 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'

var video = document.createElement('video');
console.log(Boolean(video.canPlayType(mimeType)));
```

Which returns false also, however it does play which is making me confused at how this is happening, does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening, or how I could correctly detect if the video will play or not?

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video#Streaming_File_Format_Support) is more trusted

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a way to detect support using JavaScript?

Comment: I'd use the `HTTP Live Streaming JavaScript player` mentioned in that page - I'm sure it will do what's needed and fail if it can't

Comment: Video files generally consist of a wrapper containing video, audio, and other streams. Each of those streams can be encoded with different codecs. Whether or not the browser will be able to play a file depends on which codecs are supported. However, mime type can fail to indicate these details or can be difficult to detect. So, `.canPlayType` and `.contentType` can be a probabilistic guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Can I Use HLS" page lists the compatibility matrix for the HTML5 `video` tag, meaning that it checks if the browser has **native support** for that format. For example most desktop browsers except Safari on MacOS cannot play HLS natively.

That's why for formats like Apple HLS and MPEG-DASH you need a JavaScript player which will transmux (repackage the streams without re-encoding) that specific format into one that the `video` element can process natively.

Regarding codecs you might either go for the lowest common denominator like H.264 baseline with AAC, or provide different formats tailored to the targeted device with a fallback mechanism.